# Search string in dataframe column that contains lists of string and return complete dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` which has 4 columns `'A','B','C','D'`

I have to search for a substring in each column and return the complete dataframe in the search order for example if I get the substring in column `B` row `3,4,5` then my final `df` would be having 
 `3` rows. For this I am using `df[df['A'].str.contains('string_to _search')` and it's working fine but one of the column consist each element in the column as list of strings like in column `B`

```
       A                    B        C        D
0  asdfg        [asdfgh, cvb]    asdfg   nbcjsh
1  fghjk              [ertyu]   fghhjk    yrewf
2   xcvb  [qwerr, hjklk, bnm]    cvbvb  gjfsjgf
3  ertyu              [qwert]  ertyhhu   ertkkk
```

so `df[df['A'].str.contains('string_to _search')` is not working for column `B` pls suggest how can I search in this column and maintain the order of complete dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lists in column `B`, so need `in` statement:

```
df1 = df[df['B'].apply(lambda x: 'cvb' in x)]
print (df1)
       A              B      C       D
0  asdfg  [asdfgh, cvb]  asdfg  nbcjsh
```

If want use `str.contains` then is possible use `str.join` first, so is possible search also substrings:

```
df1 = df[df['B'].str.join(' ').str.contains('er')]
print (df1)
       A                    B        C        D
1  fghjk              [ertyu]   fghhjk    yrewf
2   xcvb  [qwerr, hjklk, bnm]    cvbvb  gjfsjgf
3  ertyu              [qwert]  ertyhhu   ertkkk
```

If want search in all columns:

```
df2 = (df[df.assign(B = df['B'].str.join(' '))
           .apply(' '.join, axis=1)
           .str.contains('g')]
      )
print (df2)
       A                    B       C        D
0  asdfg        [asdfgh, cvb]   asdfg   nbcjsh
1  fghjk              [ertyu]  fghhjk    yrewf
2   xcvb  [qwerr, hjklk, bnm]   cvbvb  gjfsjgf
```